# Program in eclipse will not open says .project file is missing

Tags: java, eclipse

For Eclipse my work space is my usb drive that I've always used. I haven't used eclipse in a while so now that I'm trying to open up old projects it won't allow me to and says that my .project files are missing, but when I look at my folders on my usb there is a .project file for every project as there should be. I tried importing projects into a different work space and the projects did open up, but I'm wondering why they aren't working on my usb when that was always the workspace I've used and saved everything on. I'm a little confused and am fairly new to java programming and eclipse. Also any tips on importing/exporting projects in work spaces and using Eclipse would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Did the drive letter change? Why not just re-import the project?

Comment: If you can't find a good solution, try creating a new project and just use the .project created. You'll need to fix everything, but at leat you'll open the project in eclipse.

Comment: The answer below from @bakriawad is what I'd do too.  But as to the why part of your question, I'd guess you maybe upgraded eclipse?  It isn't that uncommon for an eclipse update to update the .project file. If the update jumps enough versions maybe the new eclipse can't figure out what to do with the old .project files.  If you're feeling particularly adventurous check out the log file  <workspace>/.metadata/.log  There's probably some info there.  Finally the .project file is just a text file and you can edit it. But importing into a new workspace is almost always the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is to try and import the project, if that doesn't work open a new project and then drag all the packages into that project then exit Eclipse, it will make a new project folder for you that works.

There is nothing to worry about here, your source code is safe anyway.